# Heroku PG error, doesn't show up in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord

I am getting this error even though my "visit_id" is defined as an integer in my db. Anyone have any sort of reason why? My local env is sqlite3 and works fine, but when I push to heroku I get this... Below is my form code.

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "visit_id"

Controller

```
      def show  
        @visit = Visit.find_by :visit_id

        respond_with(@payment)
      end

      def new
        @visit = Visit.find(params[:visit_id])
        @payment = @visit.build_payment
      end

      def create
        @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
        api = UrlApi.new()
        url = api.unique_url
        @payment.update_attribute :atapi, url
        @payment.save
        if @payment.save
          respond_with(@payment)
        else
          redirect_to edit_payment_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
        end
```

Form for payments

```
    <div class="row form">
      <div class="col-sm-6 row-col">
          <div class="box">
              <!--visits form -->
              <%= bootstrap_form_for(@payment) do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :visit_id %>
                <%= f.text_field :coupon_code %>
                <%= f.check_box :coupon_valid %>
                <%= f.check_box :paid %>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="box">
              <%= f.text_field :atapi %>
             <%= f.select :seen, 
                 [['Yes',true],['No',false]], 
                label: "Patient seen"
                <%= f.submit %>
              <% end %>
              <div class="row submit">
                  <div class="col-md-3 right">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the specific code that leads to that error? BTW, developing on SQLite and deploying on PostgreSQL is a bad idea, ActiveRecord doesn't really provide any useful portability.

Comment: I'm not seeing a specific error code from heroku logs? That is the first line that the error starts. I understand the bad ideaness of doing both pg and sqlite3, and my plan is to port development over to pg asap. I'm currently simultaneously working on learning PG while working on this app, but I don't know enough about it to get it set up correctly locally just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably right here:

```
@visit = Visit.find_by :visit_id
```

Since you're giving `find_by` something that isn't a Hash, it is probably calling `to_s` on it and producing SQL like this:

```
select visits.* from visits where visit_id limit 1
```

In PostgreSQL, each component of the WHERE clause is a boolean and since PostgreSQL has a real boolean type, it will try to interpret the identifier `visit_id` as a boolean but the `visit_id` column is an integer so you get:

> invalid input syntax for type boolean: "visit_id"

SQLite's interpretation of SQL is quite a bit looser than PostgreSQL's and it [uses C-style integers for boolean values](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean):

> **1.1 Boolean Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

so saying `where some_integer_column` makes perfect sense to SQLite.

I'd guess that your `show` controller is supposed to start with:

```
@visit = Visit.find_by(:visit_id => params[:visit_id])
```

or

```
@visit = Visit.find(params[:visit_id])
```

Comment: People smarter than me to the rescue! The second one fixed it, thank you for your time!